# Reveal hidden letters from the left by sliding to the right

Tags: html, css

I want to make the content animate so that the letters slide in to the right from the "T".

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ua27b3pz/) of the below:

```css
.two {
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}
.two:before {
  content: "T";
  width: auto;
}
.two:hover {
  width: auto;
}
.two:hover:before {
  display: none;
}
.two:hover:after {
  content: "This is a Label";
  width: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="two">
</div>
```

Comment: And how you want it to be animated (element has no content)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Animating opacity of each letter from left to right:

You could animate each letter's opacity by combining `svg`'s `linearGradient` and `mask` and using JavaScript for shifting the `x1` and `x2` attributes of the `linearGradient`on `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events.

```js
var grad = document.getElementById('gradient');
// higher 'animSpeed' yeilds lower speed
var animSpeed = 20;
var two = document.getElementsByClassName('two')[0];

two.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  for (i = 0; i < two.offsetWidth; i++) {
    var anim = setTimeout(function() {
      var x1 = (parseInt(grad.getAttribute('x1').slice(0, -1), 10) + 1) + '%';
      var x2 = (parseInt(grad.getAttribute('x2').slice(0, -1), 10) + 1) + '%';
      grad.setAttribute('x1', x1);
      grad.setAttribute('x2', x2);
    }, animSpeed * i)
  }
});

two.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  for (i = 0; i < two.offsetWidth; i++) {
    var anim = setTimeout(function() {
      var x1 = (parseInt(grad.getAttribute('x1').slice(0, -1), 10) - 1) + '%';
      var x2 = (parseInt(grad.getAttribute('x2').slice(0, -1), 10) - 1) + '%';
      grad.setAttribute('x1', x1);
      grad.setAttribute('x2', x2);
    }, animSpeed * i)
  }
})
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="-15%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="0" />
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect width="1" height="1" fill="url(#gradient)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <foreignObject width="90px" height="100%" x="2" y="12" mask="url(#mask)">
    <div class="two">This is a label</div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

---

#### Slide from left to right:

You could `transition` the `transform` property.

<kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/ua27b3pz/4/)**</kbd>

```css
.two {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.two:before {
  content: "T";
}
.two:hover:before {
  display: none;
}
.two:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "This is a Label";
  transform: translateX(-150%);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
.two:hover:after {
  content: "This is a Label";
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: Could you make it so that one you hover it shows one letter after another in an allotted time. Once I would hove over it, it would say T, then Th, and Thi and so on.

Comment: @Chase - No worries! :)

Answer (score 2):

### Reveal letters with `:before` mask

If you just want to use CSS, we can create a mask which slides over the text and then is pushed to the right to reveal the text in the div.

#### Example

```css
.two {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.two:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.6em;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.two:hover:before {
left: 100%;
}

.color:before {
  background: #F00;  
}
```

```html
<div class="two">This is a Label</div>

It looks like this (hover):

<div class="two color">This is a Label</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with just the `:before` and `:after` psuedo-elements.  Let me suggest another similar approach.

```css
/* start SLIDE-IN code */

.two > .capitalT > .else {
  position: relative;
  left: -100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: left 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}
.two > .capitalT:hover > .else {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
/* end SLIDE-IN code */
```

```html
<div class="two"><span class="capitalT"><span class="t">T</span><span class="else">his is a Label</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not capable to animate auto values in principle. So consider either

```
.two:hover::after{ width: 100px;}
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/k2wou9eh/1/ ) or other options.